# String to a list (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

```
cfgFile = { 'pers' : 20, 'source' : '[[3,"COUNTCOL","int"],[4,"COUNTROW","int"], [6,"ROWHEADER","int"],[2,"ROWCOUNT","int"]]'}
```

data could differ at times:

```
cfgFile = {'pers': 20,
           'source': '[[3,"COUNTCOL","float",2],[4, "COUNTROW", "int"],[7, "ROWHEADER", "int"],[8, "ROWHEADER", "float",2]]'}
```

'source' in the above dictionary is a list of a list as string nested in the cfgFile dictionary.

I am trying to access the very first index in each of the nested list to create another list.

```
sourceString = cfgFile.get('source')
sourceList = list(sourceString[1:-1])

print(sourceList)
```

Comment: do you have `COUNTCOL` etc, defined anywhere?

Comment: Where is the `cfgFile` data coming from?  If `source` was proper JSON, you could use `json.loads` to parse it as a list.

Comment: It's from the logs.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

cfgFile = { 'pers' : 20, 'source' : '[[3, COUNTCOL, int], [4, COUNTROW, int], [6, ROWHEADER, int], [2, ROWCOUNT, int]]' }

l = cfgFile.get("source").split(",")
[re.sub("\[*", "", l[i]) for i in range(len(l)) if i % 3 == 0]
#['3', ' 4', ' 6', ' 2']
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation to your solution!?

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to add some explanation as to what this code does and why it solves OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you want to do with the information from your log you can build your own parser, here is an example of how you could parse:

```
from itertools import repeat

def get_list(v):
    n = (int(e.group()) for e in re.finditer(r'\d', v))
    s = (e.group(1) for e in re.finditer(r'\d, ([A-Z]+),', v))

    return list(list(e) for e in zip(n, s , repeat('int')))

sourceString = cfgFile.get('source')
sourceList = get_list(sourceString)[1:-1]
print(sourceList)
```

output:

```
[[4, 'COUNTROW', 'int'], [6, 'ROWHEADER', 'int']]
```

---

since you changed you `cfgFile` in your question, you could use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval


literal_eval(sourceString)

sourceString = cfgFile.get('source')
sourceList = literal_eval(sourceString)[1:-1]

print(sourceList)
```

output:

```
[[4, 'COUNTROW', 'int'], [7, 'ROWHEADER', 'int']]
```

Comment: ```cfgFile = {'pers': 20,
           'source': '[[3,"COUNTCOL","float",2],[4, "COUNTROW", "int"],[7, "ROWHEADER", "int"],[8, "ROWHEADER", "float",2]]'}```

Comment: @Anyta check my answer, if my answer solve your issue you could upvote or accept